# Opening PDF files in Photoshop not giving the same result as original image

Tags: css, pdf, photoshop

I am trying to open a normal PDF file in Photoshop. This is how my file should look like[image]

And this is how it looks opening it on Photoshop:

Since Photoshop is not my best area i am having hard time to describe what my problem is hence the bad title. Searching in google with no knowledge of what it is was also hard.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Here is the PDF file as requested: https://files.fm/u/hq8c4kt9

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a link to your pdf file ? It seems like your pdf have ellements outside of his dimensions. You can maybe try playing with the "crop to" options in the "import pdf" dialog. (first screenshot of [this page](http://www.thearchitecturalstudent.com/2012/08/importing-pdf-into-photoshop.html))

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Just tried it but it did not work. Link has been added to the question

Comment: Sorry, missed the last step where you add a solid colour: Thank you so much! Will mark it as soon as i can

Comment: Sorry i did not understood that your problem was the background pattern. In photoshop (and some other softwares) it just mean _transparent_. And it not appears when you export the image.